# bitcoin-cli can't connect to server

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu, php, bitcoin-cli

I'm trying to put up a simple system for some penetration tests.
I have an Ubuntu server 16.04.1 with apache2 and bitcoin.
all running "Hiddn service" through tor (and bitcoind proxied 127.0.0.1:9050).
Now, using easybitcoin.php , the apache shows getinfo, send receive, all good.
but using bitcoin-cli nothing works! "couldn't connect to server"..

```
my bitcoin.conf is:
server=1
listen=1
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
rpcuser=myuser
rpcpassword=mypassword
```

Any ideas why bitcoin-cli can't connect?

Comment: Did you try using the rpcuser and password params from the cli

Comment: yes, same error.

Comment: how do you run bitcoind? with regtest?

Comment: no, just with it's conf file, no parameters. in crontab on boot.

Comment: Try issuing the command netstat -tulpn | grep bitcoin and report back what it returns

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1233/bitcoind
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8332                :::*                    LISTEN      1233/bitcoind
tcp6       0      0 :::8333                 :::*                    LISTEN      1233/bitcoind

Answer (score -2):

You should try adding `daemon=1` to your `bitcoin.conf` file.